# Setting the main icon of a CTaskDialog as a Question?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, taskdialog

I have this `CTaskDialog` that I am working on:

[image: Task Dialog]

The code is as follows:

```
CTaskDialog dlg(_T("How would you like to download the data?"), 
                _T("Download Schedule Information"),
                _T("Meeting Schedule Assistant"), TDCBF_OK_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON);
dlg.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
dlg.SetFooterIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
dlg.SetFooterText(_T("All assignments for the selected weeks will be reset."));
dlg.AddRadioButton(44444, _T("Download data for all weeks"));
dlg.AddRadioButton(44445, _T("Download data for selected week"));
dlg.AddRadioButton(44446, _T("Download data for selected week and all additional weeks"));
// Set Width in dialog units (40% screen width)
int iPixelWidth = (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 100) * 40;
int iDialogUnitsWidth = MulDiv(iPixelWidth, 4, LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()));
dlg.SetDialogWidth(iDialogUnitsWidth);

if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    auto iSelection = dlg.GetSelectedRadioButtonID();
}
```

Is it possible to set the main icon as a question? I can only see these defines in the source:

```
#define TD_WARNING_ICON         MAKEINTRESOURCEW(-1)
#define TD_ERROR_ICON           MAKEINTRESOURCEW(-2)
#define TD_INFORMATION_ICON     MAKEINTRESOURCEW(-3)
#define TD_SHIELD_ICON          MAKEINTRESOURCEW(-4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`SetMainIcon` member function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd267379) is what you're looking for. Like most functions that deal with Win32 resources, it has two overloads:

```
void SetMainIcon(
   HICON hMainIcon
);

void SetMainIcon(
   LPCWSTR lpszMainIcon
);
```

The first takes a handle to an icon resource (`HICON`), while the second takes a string identifying a resource from which an icon resource can be loaded.

If you want to set the task dialog to display your application's icon, then you can simply pass in the appropriate `HICON`. You can also use a custom icon loaded from your application's resources.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think what you're asking is how to use a question-mark icon. Note first that the use of such icons in message boxes has been deprecated since Windows 95, and Microsoft strongly discourages their use. It is recommended that you *only* use them to denote entry points to online help. Quoting from the [Standard Icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-std-icons) section of the official Win32 style guide:

> ### [Question mark icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-std-icons#question-mark-icons)
>
> - **Use the question mark icon only for Help entry points.** For more information, see the [Help entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/winenv-help) guidelines.
> - **Don't use the question mark icon to ask questions.** Again, use the question mark icon only for Help entry points. There is no need to ask questions using the question mark icon anyway it's sufficient to present a main instruction as a question.
>   **Don't routinely replace question mark icons with warning icons.** Replace a question mark icon with a warning icon only if the question has significant consequences. Otherwise, use no icon.

So, this is why there's no standard question mark icon defined. These `TD_*_ICON` defines are straight from the Win32 headers for the Task Dialog (they're the same ones you'd use with the [`TASKDIALOGCONFIG` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig)), not part of the MFC wrapper class.

If you absolutely must use this icon, the workaround is as follows:

```
const HICON hiconQuestion = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardIcon(IDI_QUESTION);
dlg.SetMainIcon(hiconQuestion);
```

(Note that the same `HICON` could be passed to the `CTaskDialog`'s `SetFooterIcon` member function.)

Comment: Thank you. I assumed a question icon since it is a question! Doh! Let me see if I can use my application icon then.

Comment: If it's in any way a destructive action, then you should use the warning icon. Otherwise, perhaps consider not using an icon at all? That's what the standard Windows apps do (e.g., Notepad, Paint, etc.).

Comment: Excellent suggestion! And thanks for the thorough answer and useful guidance.